# say shut up, say "shut up"

Tags: quotations

> People say shut up if they don't want to hear you speaking.
>
> People say "shut up" if they don't want to hear you speaking.

Do you have to enclose shut up with quotes, or is it allowed even in formal writing to write it without the quotes? I am thinking it's ok, but I am not sure. Because it's an object and not necessarily a quote (what do they say? shut up).

Comment: Personally, I would put it in quotes as it refers to someone else's speech or functions like a quote.

Comment: Where do you draw the line? Not many people would include quote marks in, say, ***People can always say no if they don't want it***. Besides which, if you *are* going to explicitly indicate "reported speech", you should probably also *capitalise* the first word of the spoken text: *People say **"Shut up"** if they don't want to hear you speaking.* (Plus of course, they *probably* say ***Shut up**!* rather than plain ***Shut up*** in such contexts.)

Answer (score 3):

Quotation marks or italics are often used to indicate that text is being used qua a sentence constituent. The text does not have to be reported speech, e.g.:

> The words "cellar door" sound beautiful to me.

As FF points out in a comment, people often omit the quotation marks or italics if the text is short. However, they can help to distinguish between [mention and use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction), so I recommend keeping them in general, especially if there is any possibility of confusion.